# Error: invalid use of template-name ‘geometry_msgs::Pose_’ without an argument list

Tags: ros, pose, geometry-msgs, posestamped

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to create a method:

```
  geometry_msgs::Pose_::_orientation_type rotationVectorToQuaternion(geometry_msgs::PointStamped::_point_type rotVec, double angle) {

    geometry_msgs::Pose_::_orientation_type quaternion;
    return quaternion;

  }
```

To set value to:

```
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped poseStamped;
poseStamped.pose.orientation = rotationVectorToQuaternion(message, angle);
```

However i get this error:

```
error: invalid use of template-name ‘geometry_msgs::Pose_’ without an argument list
   geometry_msgs::Pose_::_orientation_type rotationVectorToQuaternion(geometry_msgs::PointStamped::_point_type rotVec, double angle)
```

This is a cpp thing, but I need some help with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206340/error:-invalid-use-of-template-name-%E2%80%98geometry_msgs::pose_%E2%80%99-without-an-argument-list/) by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-31**:
Do you have a good reason for using the internal types instead of just the normal message names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the compiler would be looking for an object with type geometry_msgs::Pose not geometry_msgs::Pose_ if you `#include<geometry_msgs/Pose.h>`. Is there any particular reason why you are using the return type you are?

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on 2015-04-01**:
Yes that worked. The IDE offered me only the Pose_ one. Thanks for the help!